# Flutter - Get list of class instances inside another class with API data from different endpoints

Tags: json, flutter, dart, data-modeling

I am building a data model for soccer matches and leagues that will (hopefully) allow me to show expandable lists of soccer leagues containing future matches.

My structure works great for soccer matches, where I am able to show a list of soccer matches already. My issue occurs when I try to incorporate a League class. The league data comes from a different endpoint than the soccer match data.

My idea was to have a `List<SoccerMatch>` inside League so that a future expandable list can take all data from the League-class (List is not currently incorporated). What would be the smartest way to do this? Below is my data model for soccer data (and my API calls below that).

```
class League {
  int id;
  String name;
  String country;
  String logoUrl;
  String flag;
  String season;
  // ====== Can I add a List<SoccerMatch> here? ====

  League(
      this.id, this.name, this.country, this.logoUrl, this.flag, this.season);

  factory League.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return League(
      json['league']['id'],
      json['league']['name'],
      json['country']['name'],
      json['league']['logo'],
      json['country']['flag'],
      json['seasons'][0]['year'].toString(),
    );
  }
}

class SoccerMatch {
  Fixture fixture;
  Team home;
  Team away;
  Goal goal;
  SoccerMatch(this.fixture, this.home, this.away, this.goal);

  factory SoccerMatch.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SoccerMatch(
        Fixture.fromJson(json['fixture']),
        Team.fromJson(json['teams']['home']),
        Team.fromJson(json['teams']['away']),
        Goal.fromJson(json['goals']));
  }
}

class Fixture {
  int id;
  String date;
  Status status;
  Fixture(this.id, this.date, this.status);

  factory Fixture.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Fixture(json['id'], json['date'], Status.fromJson(json['status']));
  }
}

class Status {
  String elapsedTime;
  String long;
  String short;
  Status(this.elapsedTime, this.long, this.short);

  factory Status.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Status(json['elapsed'].toString(), json['long'], json['short']);
  }
}

class Team {
  int id;
  String name;
  String logoUrl;
  bool? winner;

  Team(this.id, this.name, this.logoUrl, this.winner);

  factory Team.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Team(json['id'], json['name'], json['logo'], json['winner']);
  }
}

class Goal {
  String home;
  String away;

  Goal(this.home, this.away);

  factory Goal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Goal(json['home'].toString(), json['away'].toString());
  }
}
```

This is my API management class. The `getLeague()` method currently returns a list of one single League instance which is not best practice. Though I couldn't get it to just return the league instance - partly because I don't fully understand the handling of the response body, I guess, but also because I am confused by how to handle it with two different endpoints.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:spark/soccer_model.dart';
import 'auth/secrets.dart';

class SoccerApi {
  static String apiKey = soccerApiKey;
  final String apiUrl = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/";

  Map<String, String> headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": apiKey,
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
  };

  Future<List<SoccerMatch>> getAllMatches(id) async {
    Response response = await get(
        Uri.parse("${apiUrl}fixtures?season=2022&league=$id"),
        headers: headers);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<dynamic> matchesList = body['response'];
      //print("API Service: $body");
      List<SoccerMatch> matches = matchesList
          .map((dynamic item) => SoccerMatch.fromJson(item))
          .toList();

      return matches;
    } else {
      throw (Exception('Error accessing API'));
    }
  }

  Future<List<League>> getLeague(leagueName, country) async {
    Response response = await get(
        Uri.parse(
            "${apiUrl}leagues?current=true&name=$leagueName&country=$country"),
        headers: headers);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<dynamic> leagueList = body['response'];
      List<League> leagues =
          leagueList.map((dynamic item) => League.fromJson(item)).toList();

      print(leagues);

      return leagues;
    } else {
      throw (Exception('Error accessing API'));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `return leagues == null || leagues.isEmpty ? null : leagues.first;`

Comment: or instead of running map: `if (!leagueList.isEmpty) { return League.fromJson(leagueList); } return null;`

Comment: The first one seems to work in regards to getting the League instance, thanks. Just need to add the list of matches under my League instance now :D